# I need to pass data from one view to another and retrieve that data on the second view

Tags: objective-c

the first view is word list view controller and it has a word table containing word_id,word meaning and sentence and this data i need to pass on the other view having 1 text field which i add to display the word and two text views to display meaning and sentence.
Here is the code-

```
- (void)getListData 
{
//tableData = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
sqlite3_stmt *statement;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"dexternotedb.sqlite"];

if (sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
    WordListViewController *temp = APP_DELEGATE.wordListViewController;
    NSLog(@"word id %ld",(long)[temp.wordId integerValue]);

    NSString *sql=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT word_id, word ,meaning,sentence FROM words WHERE word_id=\"%@\"",APP_DELEGATE.wordListViewController.wordId];
    const char *read_stmt = [sql UTF8String];
    NSLog(@"select query%@",sql);


    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, read_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK){
        //sqlite3_bind_int(statement, 1, [temp.wordId integerValue]);

        while(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
            NSString *word1 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];
            word.text = word1;
            NSString *meaning1 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)];
            meaning.text = meaning1;

            NSString *sentence1 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3)];
            Sentence.text = sentence1;



        }


        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    } else 
    {
        sqlite3_close(database);
        NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to open database with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply Store Value in NSUserDefaults

```
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"String" forKey:@"KeyName"];
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

and whenever data is required fetch data from NSUserDefaults in entire app

```
  NSString *str= [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"KeyName"];
```